# Hardware MAC address change using live CD?

Tags: windows, live-cd

I would like to save a new MAC to the hardware, so I can use the new MAC address on Windows. I am using live CD of the newest Ubuntu. If I try `ifconfig` it doesn't save it for my Windows system. I don't have admin permissions on Windows.

I need to change MAC address so the Windows one changes too.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address

Comment: mac address change for a hardware and you had to do again on every computer . if you have a live cd . you must do this every time when you boot it

Comment: @Tomasz You commented below that you have "full owner rights" to the machine. *If* this includes the right to make whatever changes you want to the installed Windows system, then the best solution to your problem might be to use the Ubuntu live CD to facilitate obtaining administrate abilities in your Windows system. Since such a procedure actually has little to with Ubuntu and much to do with Windows, it would probably be considered off-topic here, but you could ask where Windows is supported, such as [Super User](http://superuser.com/). (You should search first though, e.g. for "sethc.exe".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What network card? Some NICs store the MAC in EEPROM that can be reprogrammed by software.  If your card is setup like this, and the Linux driver exposes an interface to the EEPROM, `ethtool` (available in Ubuntu repos) can read/write to it.

[This article](http://web.archive.org/web/20130208125914/http://embedded.seattle.intel-research.net/wiki/index.php?title=Setting_the_MAC_Address_from_Linux) looks like a good overview of the process of rewriting the MAC.  Don't blindly use the examples from there though, since they may not be suited for your card.

Answer (score 1):

Run `nm-connection-editor` then click on the 'Edit...' button.

Comment: It doesn't change the mac so windows sees it. It saves it for the time the ubuntu runs.

Answer (score 1):

The MAC address is coded to the firmware of the NIC (Network Interface Card). In order to change the MAC on the card itself you would need to change the data in the firmware. The 'nm-connection-editor' doesn't do this. I don't believe there is an application under Ubuntu that does this. Even 'macchanger' is a temporary change that is reflected by the OS, not the card. 
Also, you may want to check on the legal status of what you are trying to do. Agree or not, I'm fairly sure it's a questionable practice. Especially on a machine that you don't have administrative rights on.

**Update:** You can see more about MAC address spoofing and it's implications [here](http://www.rcmp-grc.gc.ca/ncecc-cncee/factsheets-fichesdocu/macspoof-usurpmac-eng.htm). This is a Canadian website. The legal implications vary based on your location/jurisdiction.

Comment: Well I don't care about the guarantee, yet I have full owner rights of the machine. That would make the legal side clear.